# Words containing ß in Vim

Tags: vim, utf-8, diacritics

I am using gvim 7.3 on Windows to edit a German document; `enc` is `utf8`. There are words containing an "SZ", say `großer`. When my cursor is on `g`, and I press `w`, I expect the cursor to jump to the next word. Unfortunately vim seems to consider `ß` to be the border of the word and jumps to it. Anyway to tell vim it should consider `ß` a normal letter?

`ä`,`ö`,`ü` are not a problem, they are recognized correctly.

Comment: Works for me. Do you have a Vim with multibyte support? By the way: This has nothing to do with characters with "umlaut" (*ä* *ö* *ü*).

Comment: @glts oh you are right. I edited the title to catch my intention better

Comment: Another by the way: Consider making the title more descriptive, "Using w to move over words containing ß in Vim", or something ... and yes, it's *fine* to put "Vim" in the title [as long as it helps making the question clearer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179969).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Word boundaries depend on the value of the `iskeyword` option. The default value on UNIX-y systems is `@,48-57,_,192-255` which includes `ß` (#223 IIRC). Make sure you run Vim in "no compatible" mode to have the correct default value. Having a `~/.vimrc`, even an empty one, should be enough.

Comment: How? What is the value of `iskeyword`?

Comment: I added an empty .vimrc, it did not help. I also set no compatible manually, it did not help either

Comment: Please answer the questions of those who want to help you. What is the value of `:set iskeyword`?